# C# Checkbox Validator

Tags: c#, validation, checkbox

I have a Register module in my information system, setting schedule has two comboboxes "from and to" and a checkbox next to it. I would want the user to prompt the user to check at least one checkbox if he clicks register and he hasn't checked at least one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You will use the Checked property of a checkbox to see if its checked or not. And an if-else statement for your conditions.

A sample condition would look like this, assuming you are using two checkboxes. If you have additional checkbox, just add it on the if section.

```
 if (!checkBox1.Checked && !checkBox2.Checked)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Please check atleast one checkbox.");
 }
 else
  {
   //TODO: Your implementation here
   }
```

Comment: There is no specific checkbox that needs to be checked, what I wanted is at least one of the any of fhe checkbox is checked.

Comment: I updated my code. Kindly see my updated answer @Roull Hapil

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just passed my defense yester day :)